# ANOVA or multiple regression? longitudinal study

Tags: anova, multiple-regression, descriptive-statistics, biostatistics, manova

I'm doing a longitudinal study of healthy patients (so I'm studying them over time ... say at age 7,8,9,10,11,12)

I think my independent variables would be: Age (continuous) and sex (2 categories)
and dependent variables are things like cortical thickness, and functional correlation, etc.

I want to study the differences(changes) in the dependent variables over time.

My question is.. from this information I've provided.  When I want to do a statistical analysis would I do an ANOVA? or would it be multiple regression analysis?

Comment: for a longitudinal study, you should use a longitudinal analysis that is designed for a study over 'time' - mixed effects, generalized estimating equations, etc - - - ANOVA assumes that all observations are independent. A repeated measures ANOVA could be used, but that is not best used for a longitudinal analysis. Repeated measures is for a study in which repeated data point are sampled, but not necessarily for repeated measures over a particular time (that's what GEE, mixed effects are for, etc)